# Mapping <C-left> and <S-left> in Vim

Tags: vim

I've been trying to get Vim to behave a little more like ACE to no avail.

In particular, I've been trying to get Vim to accept <kbd>CTRL + LEFT</kbd> in `insert` mode as a mapping for <kbd>ESC, v, B</kbd>, and <kbd>SHIFT + LEFT</kbd> in `visual` mode as a mapping for  <kbd>B</kbd> , for example:

```
" in my ~/.vimrc:
inoremap <C-LEFT> <ESC> v B
vnoremap <S-LEFT> B
```

But these bindings seem to fail. To be clear, I get an error that says

```
E388: Couldn't find definition
```

when I try the <kbd>CTRL + LEFT</kbd> mapping:

[image: C-LEFT error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing it right. Check that nothing remaps them `:verbose map <C-LEFT>`.

Comment: `:verbose map <C-LEFT>` yields "No mapping found"...

Comment: same problem here - verbose map spits out only my definition  - pressing C-LEFT creates the ominous Couldn't find definition...

Answer (score 2):

You need to drop the spaces between the individual keys; whitespace only separates the left-hand side from the right-hand side:

```
:inoremap <C-LEFT> <ESC>vB
```

`<Space>` in normal mode is a command that moves the cursor to the right; that would interfere with the mapping.

You need to check that no other configuration / plugin remaps your left-hand side later:

```
:verbose imap <C-LEFT>
:verbose vmap <S-LEFT>
```

Also note that inside the terminal, combinations of modifier keys (like <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) and other keys may not work; this shouldn't be a problem in GVIM, though.

Comment: Please see edited version. I'm getting an E388 error... Also, I'm not using `gvim`, but proper `vim` (inside tmux)...

Comment: Do other mappings work? What if you replace `<C-Left>` with an inconspicuous `abc`?

Comment: What if you type that `:inoremap <C-LEFT> ...` into a running Vim session? If it then works, something's deleting your mapping after your .vimrc.

Comment: This `E349` is on use, right? You do get a listing with `:verb imap <C-LEFT>` now, right? It looks like your terminal doesn't support those keys. Instead, those keys send strange sequences which Vim misinterprets.

Comment: Correct, `E349` is on use, and `:verb imap ...` does post the proper listing. Final note: `:echo $TERM` yields `xterm-256color`...